# Nullcheck method using java8 method reference possible?

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Due to rich profiling, our Java code is cluttered with outputs of method results of nullable objects.

It looks like this

```
namedObject == null ? "?" : namedObject.getName()
```

is it possible to write a static method for this? (e.g. looking like this):

```
Util.nvl( namedObject, NamedObject::getName, "?" )
```

What would = Util.nvl look like? I've experimented a bit an searched google but yielded no result.

This does not work:

```
public static <T> T nvl(T value, Function<T, ?> method, T nullSubstition) {
    return value == null ? nullSubstition : (T) method.apply(value);
}
```

The compiler tells me:
non-static method getName() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your signature can't be correct. You want your method to take the NamedObject as first argument (so T is a NamedObject), and to return a String (so now T is String).

You need two generic type parameters:

```
public class Utils {

    public static <O, T> T nvl(O value, Function<O, T> method, T nullSubstition) {
        return value == null ? nullSubstition : method.apply(value);
    }

    static class NamedObject {
        String getName() {
            return "foo";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NamedObject foo = null;
        String name = Utils.nvl(foo, NamedObject::getName, "bar");
        System.out.println("name = " + name); // name = bar

        foo = new NamedObject();
        name = Utils.nvl(foo, NamedObject::getName, "bar");
        System.out.println("name = " + name); // name = foo
    }
}
```

An even better signature, allowing more flexibility, would be

```
public static <O, T> T nvl(O value, Function<? super O, ? extends T> method, T nullSubstition) {
    return value == null ? nullSubstition : method.apply(value);
}
```

Comment: It's not an "nvl" operation, though, it's a "getOrDefault" operation.

Answer (score 5):

Your method's generics aren't defined correctly. You're attempting to create a method that receives an object of a certain type (`T`, for argument's sake, or a `NamedObject` in the given example), and applies a method that returns an object of a different type (`S`, for argument's sake, or `String` in the given example), or a default `S` value if the passed object is `null`:

```
public static <T, S> S nvl(T value, Function<T, S> method, S nullSubstition) {
    return value == null ? nullSubstition : (S) method.apply(value);
}
```

Note that Java 8's [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) may allow you to write this in a more elegant way (although elegance is somewhat in the eye of the beholder):

```
public static <T, S> S nvl(T value, Function<T, S> method, S nullSubstition) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(value).map(method).orElse(nullSubstition);
}
```

Comment: @PatrickParker yes. Got ahead of myself there :-) Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing!

Comment: nice example. maybe a good name for this function would be `optionalMapOrElse`, since it is shorthand for that notation.

Comment: @PatrickParker I stuck with the OP's name. I believe it's taken from Oracle's SQL [`nvl`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm).